# 5.1.1 notification TextView, the correct way to deal with white text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I put a TextView on a custom layout for a notification. The colour of the TextView becomes automatically white. **Is this a bug of Android?** Because prior to Lollipop, notification background used to be a dark colour, so a white text made sense. Now on Lollipop, the default background is white, so the white text is invisible.

**Or am I supposed to set text colour explicitely?** Putting android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" made the text black, but it is not guaranteed that all Lollipop devices have white notification background, is it?

**What is the correct way to guarantee that the text on a custom notification is always visible regardless of the background colour of the system?**

Preview on Android Studio

[image: Preview on Android Studio]

On an actual 5.1.1 device

[image: On actual 5.1.1 device]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, world"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone still looking for a solution for this question, I think that the best alternative is to define the style of your `TextView` to

```
TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent
```

prior to lollipop, and

```
@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title
```

for APIs >=21. Something like this

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="NotificationTextColor.Title" parent="TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"></style>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="NotificationTextColor.Title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title"></style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/NotificationTextColor.Title"
    tools:text="text"/>
```