# Android custom notification not showing code changes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

There's some weird behavior here. I've got a bunch of code, pictures, followed by some description of the weird behavior and **then** my questions.

**Files**

I have a file `random_start_bonus_cards_notification.xml`, which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstCard" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondCard" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ifNotCoal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="("
            android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/if_not_coal"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thirdCard" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=")"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And a file `random_start_bonus_cards.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
```

This is a deliberately blank layout, because of weirdness we'll get into. It turns out this file has to be here, but it doesn't matter what it contains.

Annnnd my `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

<style name="NotificationTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="NotificationText">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>
```

And some Android code:

```
    private void showStartBonusCardsDialog(DrawnCards drawnCards) {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(CalculatorActivity.this);
    final View dialogContent = factory.inflate(R.layout.random_start_bonus_cards_notification, null);
    ((ImageView) dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.firstCard)).setImageResource(getDrawableIdForStartCard(drawnCards.firstCard()));
    ((ImageView) dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.secondCard)).setImageResource(getDrawableIdForStartCard(drawnCards.secondCard()));

    if(drawnCards.hasThirdCard()) {
        dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.ifNotCoal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ImageView) dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.thirdCard)).setImageResource(getDrawableIdForStartCard(drawnCards.thirdCard()));
    } else {
        dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.ifNotCoal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    AlertDialog drawnCardsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalculatorActivity.this).create();
    drawnCardsDialog.setView(dialogContent);
    drawnCardsDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.dismiss(); }
    });
    drawnCardsDialog.show();
}

private void showStartBonusCardsNotification(DrawnCards drawnCards) {
    Intent openIntent = new Intent(CalculatorActivity.this, CalculatorActivity.class);
    openIntent.setAction(refreshStartCardsAction);
    PendingIntent openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openIntent, 0);

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.random_start_bonus_cards_notification);
    notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.firstCard, getDrawableIdForStartCard(drawnCards.firstCard()));
    notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.secondCard, getDrawableIdForStartCard(drawnCards.secondCard()));
    if(drawnCards.hasThirdCard()) {
        notificationView.setViewVisibility(R.id.ifNotCoal, View.VISIBLE);
        notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.thirdCard, getDrawableIdForStartCard(drawnCards.thirdCard()));
    } else {
        notificationView.setViewVisibility(R.id.ifNotCoal, View.GONE);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.white);
    notification.setContentIntent(openPendingIntent);
    notification.setContent(notificationView);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int notificationId = 1;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification.build());
}
```

And here's two screenshots to refer to:
[image: Dialog]
[image: Notification]

**Weirdness**

I initially had just one layout file, since the layouts were identical. With this, the text colour of the dialog was black (good) and the text colour of the notification was white and couldn't be read on my HTC M9.

(1) If I put the XML from `random_start_bonus_cards_notification.xml` into `random_start_bonus_cards.xml`, and replace all usages of `random_start_bonus_cards_notification` with `random_start_bonus_cards`, the text colours are wrong. If I keep the code as-is, but delete `random_start_bonus_cards`, the text colours are wrong. If I use `random_start_bonus_cards_notification.xml` and keep `random_start_bonus_cards.xml` in the project, even if it's empty, *I get black text in both the dialog and notification!*

(2) The background on the notification is a pale green. This colour was in the resource file at one point, but has been removed (as shown). After removing the background colour the dialog layout has a white background, but the notification background is still pale green, no matter whether I change it to red or anything.

(3) If I stop calling the dialog code, the same behavior occurs. I've included the dialog code since I'm worried there might be some interaction here, but I don't see how.

**Questions**

Generally, how does RemoteViews work with custom notification layouts? Is there any kind of system caching that could account for the background colour not changing?

Why is my notification not changing background colour when I change the layout background colour?

Why does my app change behavior when I delete this empty file `random_start_bonus_cards.xml`, that isn't even being used?

Why does my notification text colour not work unless I use the file named `random_start_bonus_cards_notification.xml`? (If I remove the `_notification`, the text changes colour).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was maddening, and is still not great.

(1) After confirming that my phone was doing some caching, I started using the emulator and it worked better.

(2) I left the notification with a separate layout files from the dialog, even though they are identical. My reasoning is that apparently the notification background can change between Android releases (there's a lot of complaints).

(3) I didn't post it above, but at one point I had a "v9/styles.xml". I didn't realize this applied to *all* versions above API9.

The final solution looks a bit like the following code. I copied from this SO answer ([5.1.1 notification TextView, the correct way to deal with white text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602738/5-1-1-notification-textview-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-white-text)) and used textAppearance instead of style.

```
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/if_not_coal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/NotificationText"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />
```

*textAppearance* is great.

```
<style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
```

Gives the text a greyish colour for < API 21.

```
<style name="NotificationText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title"></style>
```

Gives the text a black colour for API >= 21.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that this is happenning for one of the following two reasons:

1. The first of these could be that somewhere else in your code, you are refering to the creation of the notification, and there the changes you have made would not affect the code.
2. This is more likely to happen. The build has broken down and your built version of the app is not using the latest code. You can solve this by rebuilding the app from your IDE.

If you still can't manage to get hold of why this is happenning, set a breakpoint just before calling the method to display the notification and follow the logic the app is using.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these are the reason, that I can see. I put some stuff back, and now my notification is a lighter gray where the dialog is black text. It's readable, but not perfect how I want it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I did confirm that without cleaning the project, no changes were made to the running app. I wonder if the incremental build is busted? 

I ended up make _ and _notifications identical except for styles, added some styles to the notification and used @android:color/primary_text_light as a text colour. Which goes against all of the prevailing wisdom on this stuff.

But it's a hobby project, so someone can complain if it doesn't work for them...>.>

Comment: Have you tried debugging the logic which is displaying the notification? The text color is controlled by the value of `textColorPrimaryInverse` so check the value in the strings.xml file. There must be some logic which is busting the build and forcing you to clean each time you make an update to the code.

Comment: Thanks for your eyeballs! I found a solution that isn't terrible, and posted about it below.